# using generics without changing the class header

Tags: java, class, generics

Lets say I have two classes. `Pair`:

```
public class Pair<X, Y> {
 public X x;
 public Y y;

  public Pair(X x , Y y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
  }
}
```

and the class `Triple`:

```
public class Triple<X, Y, Z> {
 public X x;
 public Y y;
 public Z z;

 public Triple(X x , Y y, Z z) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
 }
}
```

And I want to create a class `Test` without changing the class header (can't do `Test<X, Y, Z>`):

```
public class Test {
  ...
}
```

In this class should be a method, that takes a list of `Triples` and should return a Map with the x-value of the triple as a key and the y and z-values of the triple as the value of the map.

How can I do this without changing the class header?

Comment: Sounds like a generic method is all you need: `public static <X,Y,Z> Map<X,Pair<Y,Z>> convert(List<Triple<X,Y,Z>> list) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it. You need to make the method generic rather than the class it's in.

```
class Test {

    static <X, Y, Z> Map<X, Pair<Y, Z>> makeMap(List<Triple<X, Y, Z>> triples) {        
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

The method could be `static` or non-`static`. In either case, the generic parameters `<X, Y, Z>` appear immediately before the return type.

Comment: Thank you! Does the method need to be static or why have you Chosen it to be static?

Comment: I don't know why I made it static. In general it's better to avoid static methods as they make testing harder.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, here an implementation:

```
public static <X, Y, Z> Map<X, Pair<Y, Z>> makeMap(List<Triple<X, Y, Z>> arg) {
    return arg.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.x, e -> new Pair<>(e.y, e.z)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Does the method need to be static or why have you Chosen it to be static?

Comment: it does not need to be static. But there is no reason why it should not be static.